# User cannot bring up keyboard when tapping in uitextfield

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a user who cannot bring up the keyboard when she taps in the textfield of my iPad app. There are over 100 users who have no trouble doing this, and I cannot find a way to reproduce her problem (I've observed everything working correctly on 12 different devices). She insists that she has tapped in the text field and that nothing happens. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

I welcome your thoughts on this one. Thanks!

UPDATE: Another user has just reported a similar problem. While initially I thought this may be a PEBKAC, but since two independent people are having the same issue, that is becoming less likely.

Comment: Sometimes when the device is at a funny angle it doesn't register a tap (upside down or at 90 deg?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one of the users:

> I updated the software from 3.2.2 to
>   the latest version 4.1.1 and did a
>   firmware update.  The app works fine
>   now!

Odd, since I back tested it, but at least the problem is resolved at last.

UPDATE: The second user also confirms that this solution worked. I'd love to hear if anyone else experienced similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Does she have long fingernails? Does she tap with her index finger, but allow her middle finger to touch the screen at the same time? Does she drag a bit when she taps?

Can somebody else using her device get the keyboard to appear?

I wouldn't consider it a code problem until you eliminate user error.

If it is a code problem, check that some other view isn't overlapping your textfield and intercepting touches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll ask her to have someone else try to use her device.

Answer (score 0):

Does she have a Bluetooth keyboard connected?